# I am Facing Issue while Running React-Native App on Emulator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I run the command with cmd on vs-code **"`npx react-native run-android`
**i get this error**

## FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

## What went wrong:

## Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

## Could not determine the dependencies of null.

## java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwNFo.png)
**My Enviromental Setup:
**
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Ygx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilZ91.png)
I Setup Enviromental Setup again and Again, also Restart Device, Change Emulator 2 Times, And i am Suprise coz once first time when i run the command i did dont get any error, and application is sucefully run on emulator, later when i try next time start facing this issue.